# Can i check if theres any data sent to my server without waiting for it

Tags: c++, tcp, server

The reason I want this is because i want to send messages as the server. But when i wait for data it blocks me from sending any data. I've tried multithreading but it didnt work.

```
int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);
```

Im using this line of code to receive the data. But like I said it blocks me from sending data from the server without the other end sending anything to me.

Comment: What do you mean "I've tried multithreading but it didnt work."? Can you share your code?

Comment: Did you consider using boost::asio?

Comment: You can use `select` on Windows or Linux

Comment: So apart from the main function I have a thread that runs a function that checks NUMPAD0 so I can send data from server. But the recv function still blocks me from doing that it requires to get data from the recv function to get to the point that I can send data, so I tried using the recv function in another thread and it didnt work so I thought I'd ask it here.